# How to find the list of databases within an AWS Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to list out all the existing databases within a Redshift cluster. How can I do that.

What SQL query can I fire such that it sends me a list of all the databases within the AWS cluster

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Please try this.

```
    SELECT * FROM pg_database;
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM PG_DATABASE_INFO` also works https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_DATABASE_INFO.html